# How do I reconnect a socket using Mina

Tags: java, sockets, reconnect

Now I have a java application using Mina,when socket is connecting to server,I think this java application is normal,else abnormal. In brief,I implement application status monitor using socket long connection.The problem is how do I reconnect a socket using Mina,or is there another better way to implement application status monitor. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reconnect any TCP socket. You have to close it and start again with a new one, same way you got the first one.